# Jquery fails to hide div in IE10 running in IE7 document and browser mode

Tags: jquery, dom, internet-explorer-7

I have written a small jQuery script that queries the url to see if it contains certain text (in this case a PL/SQL generated parameter and value). If so, the script hides a div in the page content and adjusts the adjacent divs to fill the space left by the now absent div. My current issue is that for some reason the script isn't working in IE7 despite working in all other browsers.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
        if(window.location.href.indexOf("p_ccp_path=APPLY") != -1){
          $(".page-content-right").hide();
          $("#right-col").css("width","60%");
          $("#icams-inserted").css("width","100%");
        }
      });
    </script>
```

I'm using a localised version of jQuery 1.10.2 and the page on which this error is occurring can be found here:

http://tinyurl.com/jqueryError

Any ideas?

Additional:

I've checked Firebug and there are no errors. However, when I check the IE developer tool it comes up with the following error:

```
  SCRIPT3: Member not found
  jquery.min.js, line 5 character 8860
```

Additional2:

From some of the comments, it appears that this may be an issue with the IE10 render as IE7 mode. I'm going to test this on a Vanilla version of IE7 on virtual box to make sure that this is the case.

Comment: Any reason to still support IE7? BTW, how to reproduce your issue on your site?

Comment: You are using an ancient version of jQuery and an ancient browser. Is it really important for those dinosaurs to work?

Comment: @KamilT jQuery 1.10.2 is the most recent. :)

Comment: @KamilT jq 1.10.2 is not really an ancient jquery version

Comment: I get a semantic problem reported in Safari 6 when opening your site.

Comment: @insertusernamehere ya, the most recent stable version for the 1.x branche

Comment: I assume you've dropped IE6 support already? The best advice I can give you is to drop IE7 support as well. Its usage has fallen away much quicker than IE6 did; its down to [about half a percent on the UK stats](http://gs.statcounter.com/) now, so it's barely higher than IE6. Not worth the effort.

Comment: @roasted Yeah of course, but if you want to support IE7 then there's no other branche than 1.x. ;) But I get your point.

Comment: It is worth the effort as a majority of our corporate clients who use our system, still use IE7. With regards to the jQUery version being ancient, that's just plain wrong. If you go to the jQuery website it's actually given preference over 2.x

Comment: @insertusernamehere i get your point too ;)

Comment: I get the following error when opening that page `Uncaught Error: InvalidCharacterError: DOM Exception 5`

Comment: @Pete Which browser are you using? Safari? We don't have the capacity to test this browser as we have no Macs in the office.

Comment: insertusernamehere ,roasted - my bad, I read 1.1.2, which would be from Feb 2007 :)

Comment: I'm not getting any errors in my Firebug console so where are you guys seeing these errors?

Comment: @jezzipin could you check your console using IE7 for any error. BTW, check if `window.location.href` returns expected result in IE7

Comment: According to my IE console it's the jquery core library that has an issue. I'm getting Member not found.

Comment: so test to dowgrade your jq version and BTW why not posting which error  message you have??? Even in IE error msg are rarely usefull

Comment: Already tested downgrading the jQuery version. Same issue. SCRIPT3: Member not found
  jquery.min.js, line 5 character 8860

Comment: You should use a non minified jquery version and debug from it and see what cause this issue, looks like the "novalidate" attribute setted to the form

Comment: @roasted See below. I've found the solution to the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that this is a bug with IE10 itself rather than there actually being any errors in my code. Testing a stock version of IE7 on a remote machine showed that the script does indeed work on IE7 without a hitch.

To ensure that the issue does not persist if users are running their browser in compatability mode, I have used the following meta tag:

```
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
```

This ensures that the most recent version of IE standards mode is used when running in IE compatibility mode through the use of the 'Edge' specification.

Credit to @MythThrazz for the suggestion that it may be an issue with the IE10 compatability mode.

Comment: Thx to share it, could be usefull for other people but you should have mentionned it in your question than you were using IE7 compatibility mode, not IE7 ;) Oh, i see you mention it now in your question, great! :)

Comment: It's pretty much the same. It gives more or less the same visual appearance etc. when designing and more or less developing it just appears there are some issues with jQuery support so I'll be using my virtual machines in future.

Comment: It is more or less the same but not THE same (also because of this bug and probably some others).

Answer (score 2):

Googling for the error code points to this url: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12577

The error may not related with the part of the code you've posted.

Comment: I just checked that there is a `jquery.validate.min.js` loaded on the page.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is `.indexof()`.

It is supposed to be camel-case, so it should be `.indexOf()` (with a capital `O`). Javascript cares about this sort of thing, so I'm surprised if that would work in *any* browser.

Comment: Not the case. I've tried it with both on IE7 and it doesn't work.

Comment: @jezzipin For sure it is indexOf() not indexof()

Comment: I know. That was a mis-type in my question above. I'm actually using it camel-cased already so this is not what is causing the issue.

Comment: fair enough. I see you've edited the question to fix that now.