# Jquery hide() show() does not work internet explorer 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I've got a problem with jquery hide() and show() on internet explorer 10. I need a pop-up window for a banner I'm making, when clicking left bottom corner a div will show, when div is up and clicking on top right corner div will hide.

This work on modern browser, but not in internet explorer 10.

HTML

```
<div id="banner">
<button class="show"></button>
<div id="modal">
<button class="hide"></button>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#banner {
width: 468px;
height: 240px;
border: solid 1px black;
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;
}

#modal {
width: 468px;
height: 240px;
display: none;   
position: absolute;
z-index: 9999;
background-color: red;
}

.show {
width: 80px;
height: 35px;
bottom: 0px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 12;
}

.hide {
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
position: absolute; 
z-index: 12;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".hide").click(function(){
    $("#modal").hide();
});
$(".show").click(function(){
    $("#modal").show();
});
});
```

**EDIT - problem solved**
It appears you cannot click empty  tags (only specified width/height) in IE 10 and below, so I had to fill it with a transperant color (rgba 0,0,0,0.001).

I also realized it could be done without jquery, duh.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery fails to hide div in IE10 running in IE7 document and browser mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724437/jquery-fails-to-hide-div-in-ie10-running-in-ie7-document-and-browser-mode)

Comment: When you say that it doesn't work, what do you mean exactly? What happens when you try it? Do you get any error message?

Comment: The modal won't display on IE 10 when i push the button, but it works on other browsers.

Comment: So make an answer and mark it as the solution.

Comment: Please remove "Solved" from your title and question and add it as an answer. You can even mark it as "Accepted" if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use vanilla JS, and do something like:

```
document.getElementById('modal').style.display = 'block';
```

or

```
document.getElementById('modal').style.display = 'none';
```

This way is also more performance efficient than going through a jQuery object.

Comment: It should, I would be shocked it if didn't.

Comment: Haha I would be extremely concerned for all webpages if it didn't!

Answer (score 0):

Hide and Show methods of Jquery toggles the CSS property display to none/block for applied HTML tag.So question rules out about compatibility. 
Just correct the error on console of browser (F12) if any (I saw one unreferenced object) and try again . 
Also, check the browser mode you are running. (F12).

Comment: thank you, will defenitly do this when i can access ie10